# What is the active:true construct in Angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I am following the phonecat Angular tutorial [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_12) and I was wondering what this code was doing:

```
<div class="phone-images">
  <img ng-src="{{img}}"
       class="phone"
       ng-repeat="img in phone.images"
       ng-class="{active:mainImageUrl==img}">
</div>
```

- Is {active:true} an angular construct? If so, what does it do and where   is the documentation? Why the single {}?
- Will {{img}} work in ng-src even though it's above the ng-repeat line?

Comment: I flagged as too broad. First you are asking "how does this code work?" Second, you ask followup questions. You are not asking about a specific issue, but rather for help with a tutorial. If the tutorial has a forum, I suggest you ask there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) is a directive, that expects an Angular expression. The type of the expression can be a string (the name of the class), an array of strings (the names of the classes), or an object where keys are the names of the classes, and values are booleans telling if the class must be added or not.

In that case, the expression is a literal JavaScript object, just as you would write it in JavaScript code:

```
var object = {active: mainImageUrl == img};
```

And the CSS class 'active' will thus be added if `mainImageUrl == img` is true.